# How can I close my own bad question after putting a bounty on it?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, active-bounties

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565925/sqlite-rename-empty-table) about a problem that can not be reproduced. I was assuming a database state that was not correct (a query on a table that does not exist).

It's fine if the points are gone, but I want to close the question. What is the correct way to handle this situation? At the moment there are no answers yet and I flagged it for closing (I'm not sure if a question with a bounty can be closed though).

Answer (score 3):

Flag for moderator attention. Be thorough in your flag description. Explain the circumstances and your motivations.

A question with an active bounty can't be closed/deleted. The bounty needs to be removed first.

Depending on the situation (e.g. how much effort users spent attempting to answer your question), the handling moderator may decide it's better to refund the bounty and delete the question.

But if they see the bounty is relatively advanced and/or other users already posted answers, they can also decline your flag and let the bounty run its course.

If it's early enough, trying to delete it before attracts additional attention could be a good thing. Since bounties can easily attract low quality answers that may make harder deleting the question later.

Just don't make a habit of this, some mods run a policy of "just once" for this kind of thing.

Answer (score -2):

You can either flag for moderator attention, or just do nothing.

The bounty will expire in 7 days or sooner; afterwards, you can delete it yourself. There are thousands of bad questions on Stack Overflow which don't get closed because there are too few caretakers; one more won't make a difference.

Comment: Questions that have answers with awarded bounties cannot be deleted by their authors. If an answer gets posted and it meets the criteria for an automatic award, the question cannot be deleted regardless of the answer's score or the non-presence of other answers.

Comment: The situation described by the OP doesn't sound like a question which should receive an answer, let alone an upvoted one.